# Can not compile merge sort tree structure?

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, tree, mergesort

> I was trying to implement merge sort tree structure but whenever i
>   try to merge child vector to parent vector i get compilation error . I
>   am stuck here .

```
 class merge_sort_tree {

    vector<int>input;
    vector<vector<int> >tr;
    int n;
public:

    merge_tree(vector<int >p) {
        n = p.size();
        input = p;
        tr.resize(5 * n);
    }

    void build(int root, int l, int r) {
        if (l == r)
        {
            tr[root] = {input[l]};
        }

        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

        build(2 * root, l, m);
        build(2 * root + 1, m + 1, r);

       //temporary vector for merging child vectors 

        vector<int>tmp(tr[2 * root].size() + tr[2 * root + 1].size());  

       // merging child vector and storing result in tmp

        merge(tr[2 * root].begin(), tr[2 * root].end(),
              tr[2 * root + 1].begin(), tr[2 * root + 1].end(),
              tmp.begin(), tmp.end() );

         tr[root]=tmp;
    }
};
```

[image]

In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:40,
               c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\stdc++.h:52,
                 from C:\Users\Ayuu\Desktop\codes\test3.cc:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator1, _Iterator2) [with _Iterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Iterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:4751:14:   required from '_OutputIterator std::__merge(_InputIterator1, _InputIterator1, _InputIterator2, _InputIterator2, _OutputIterator, _Compare) [with _InputIterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _InputIterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _OutputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:4858:37:   required from '_OIter std::merge(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _IIter2, _OIter, _Compare) [with _IIter1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _IIter2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _OIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >]'
C:\Users\Ayuu\Desktop\codes\test3.cc:43:38:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h:123:18: error: no match for call to '(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >) (int&, int&)'
         { return bool(_M_comp(*__it1, *__it2)); }

Comment: Start by examining the line of code and error description as given in the error message. It's talking about line 123 of `predefined_ops.h`. I have no idea what code you're showing.

Comment: Post the errors _as text_, not an image.

Comment: Look here: ***predefined_ops.h:123:18:** error: no match for call...*. Line 123, character position 18. That's where it's pointing you.

Comment: but their is no 123 line in my programm ! .

Comment: The output message has `std::merge` in it.  Your code calls `merge`.  Maybe start there?

Comment: i was passing 6 argument in merge .

Comment: Which version of [std::merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) matches the arguments you're passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line, it expected one iterator, you gave 2
error: no match for call to '(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >) (int&, int&)' { return bool(_M_comp(*__it1, *__it2)); }

Remove tmp.end() from your merge function. It requires 5 arguments not 6.

```
    merge(tr[2 * root].begin(), tr[2 * root].end(),
          tr[2 * root + 1].begin(), tr[2 * root + 1].end(),
          tmp.begin());
```

This should work.